# Fetch data from MongoDB Cloud

Tags: mongodb, web, deployment

To use axios.get on local mongodb, I write the path as "localhost:4000/v1/api/products" to get products from local mongodb collections.

Now how to write the path after deployment??

I tried just "v1/api/products" or "/products" but nothing seems to be working.

The product collection is already made and has the required input.

Edit :

I have deployed my Ecommerce website on render.
Photos :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTY1K.png)
Here, you can see the server is working fine and the mongodb cloud is also connected.

But the website runs without server, only frontend is visible.

Photo : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQmA8.png)

Here I tried setting the PORT as the same on Render, but still the server is not fetching from Mongodb cloud.

When on local sysyem, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: After deployment of what, the app or the database?

Comment: Both. I have updated my question to include more details. Please check. Thank you

Comment: I think you may be mixing up two things. The user (via their browser) connects only to the app. The app, and only the app, talks to the database. The endpoints for the app are associated with the location that the app is deployed. Eg when I go to `https://savvy-vaqt.onrender.com/products` I get some payload text back (`{"success":true,"products":[{"_id":"63d53949e18079bbe3548aa2","name":"Guerlain Shalimar Perfume", "description" ... "__v":0}],"ProductCount":2}`

Comment: Yes I understood. I kind of mixed those two together. I have one question. I have deployed my frontend on netlity, and changed the frontend fetch URL to the savvy.... but  its showing page does not exist. Can you tell where I am making a mistake??